# iPhone accessory, accessory protocol empty

Tags: xcode, external-accessory

I am working on an app that has an external accessory, the phone shows that it has been authenticated and the device shows up in the General->About menu, but when I NSlog the accessory protocols, it shows up as Null, I didn't think that should be possible if an accessory is actually authenticated.

Is there anything I can do in my app to force the accessory to reauthenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that for some reason when the device first paired, some of the information was getting garbled, we ended up putting a 2 second delay in place after the bluetooth chipset had paired on the accessory side and then started our authentication. For some reason the bluetooth chipset was still doing some of it's own processing and wasn't quite ready to start streaming data.

Answer (score 0):

can you explain it better?

Anyway, did you remember to put the protocol string in the [YourApp]-info.plist file?
No? Add this row:

```
UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols
```

Add a string item to this new row and put inside the string identifing your protocol.

Comment: Yes, that is in there. The problem was that for some reason when the device first paired, some of the information was getting garbled, we ended up putting a 2 second delay in place after the bluetooth chipset had paired on the accessory side and then started our authentication.  For some reason the bluetooth chipset was still doing some of it's own processing and wasn't quite ready to start streaming data.